# работа с абстрактным классом Java

Tags: java, ооп, spring-boot

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переписать этот код?

```
@Service
public class Manager {
    @Autowired
    private StorageOne one;
    @Autowired
    private StorageTwo two;

    public void save() {
       one.save();
       two.save();
    }
}

@Component
public class StorageOne {

    public void save() {
       ......
    }
}

@Component
public class StorageTwo {

    public void save() {
       ......
    }
}
```

я хочу в менаджере избавиться от

```
@Autowired
private StorageOne one;
@Autowired
private StorageTwo two;

public void save() {
   one.save();
   two.save();
}
```

и сделать, что то типо:

```
@Service
public class Manager {
  @Autowired
  private AbstrackStorage stor;

  public void save() {
   stor.save();
  }
}
```

что бы при вызове вот этого абстрактного класса, отрабатывали переопределенные методы в стораджах, возможно ли это?)

Comment: ты хочешь выбирать одно из хранилищей на лету (или при старте) или сохранять во все доступные? Если во все, то ответ тебе уже дали (`@Autowired     private List<Storage> storages;`). Если выбирать одно какое-то на старте, то надо создавать компоненты по условию, чтобы Спрингу был известен только один и именно его вставят в `Manager`

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov да, во все) спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
public interface Storage {

    void save();
}

@Component
public class StorageOne implements Storage {

    public void save() {
        ......
    }
}

@Component
public class StorageTwo implements Storage {

    public void save() {
        ......
    }
}

@Service
public class Manager {

    @Autowired
    private List<Storage> storages;

    public void save() {
        for (Storage storage : storages) {
            storage.save();
        }
    }
}
```